# Can we automate remote machine using UI automation

Tags: c#, automation, microsoft-ui-automation

I have code which logs into rdp, but I am not able to inspect any element:

```
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Automation;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions;


namespace AutoTest
{
    class RAAdmin
    {
        public void RuleTestExistingUserName()
        {
            var RDP = Process.Start("mstsc.exe");
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
            var _remoteRDP = AutomationElement.RootElement.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "Remote Desktop Connection"));
            AutomationElement rdpCombobox = AutomationElement.RootElement.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ClassNameProperty, "ComboBox"));
            AutomationElement rdpTextBox = AutomationElement.RootElement.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ClassNameProperty, "Edit"));
            TextPattern targetTextPattern =              rdpTextBox.GetCurrentPattern(TextPattern.Pattern) as TextPattern;
            targetTextPattern.DocumentRange.Select();
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
            SendKeys.SendWait("xxx.xxx.xx.xx");
            rdpCombobox = AutomationElement.RootElement.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ClassNameProperty, "ComboBox"));
            _remoteRDP = AutomationElement.RootElement.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "Remote Desktop Connection"));
            SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");
//clicks on connect button of rdp window.
```

I am able to login to rdp but not able to inspect the elements in the remote machine window.  Please provide thoughts.

Comment: What is the OS version on the target machine (and on the client)?   I believe that RDP *can* forward UI Automation requests on Windows 8 and above; but both the client and target must be running Windows 8 or above.

Comment: Os on both machines is 8.1 windows, I am not able to inspect the elements

Comment: I was wrong.  RDP does not forward UI Automation requests.

Comment: If the targeted tool that needs to be automated and the app with the UIAutomation code reside on the server, is it possible to automate the tool on the remote machine.

Answer (score 1):

RDP does not forward UI Automation requests over to the remote machine, so you will not be able to discover or inspect elements in the remote machine window.